# Добавить тег в середине строки

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Может быть это тупой вопрос, но все же. У меня есть `div`, в нем `ul` там `li` и внем `p`. Так как я делаю адаптивный сайт, мне свойство css `p {max-width: 100%}` не помогает, текст все равно вылазит за пределы экрана. Так вот я хочу с помощью `jQuery` добавить в середину строки тег `br`. Как это реализовать? Вот структура:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html {width: 100%;}
html:lang(en) {quotes: "\201C" "\201D";}
* {font-family: Arial, Myriad Pro, PT Sans ,Tahoma, Times New Roman,  sams-serif; hyphens: auto;}
body {background-color: blueviolet; background-repeat: no-repeat;    background: radial-gradient(ellipse 95% 95%, #8B30A1,#74229A, blueviolet); margin: 0; padding: 0; background-position: center;}
button {cursor: pointer;}
body {hyphens: auto;}
button:focus {border: 0}
div.block3 p {display: inline; margin: 0; color: #E2DDDD; font-size: 0.96em; padding: 0} 
div.block3 {margin: 0px 6px 0px 25px;}
div.block3 img {width: 70px; height: 70px; margin: 9px 0px 0px -3px;}
div.block3 ul {margin: -35px 0px 40px 55px; color: #D5D3D3;}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : portrait) {
div.block3 {width: 100%; margin: 0;}
div.block3 img {width: 96px; height: 96px; display: block; margin: 10px auto;}
div.block3 ul {margin: 10px 0px 30px -22px; width: 100%;}
}
</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="block3">
<img src="media/images/Twittlogo.jpg" alt="Twitterlogo"/>
<ul>
 <li><p>Go this link (<a href="https://twitter.com/RayEugen" target="_blank">https://twitter.com/RayEugen</a>).</p></li>
</ul> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Потому, что выходит вот так (края блока это конец экрана смартфона):

[image: края блока это конец экрана смартфона]

Comment: Добавьте блоку `padding` и убедитесь, что не отключены переносы. Без более полного кода трудно что-то сказать.

Comment: @br3t У body стоит hyphens: auto, у p: padding: 0. Не слишком помогло.

Comment: Давайте полностью код, который воспроизводит проблему

Comment: @br3t вам полностью страницу скинуть?

Comment: Лучше нужный код в сниппет здесь, вам будет проще отделить нужный код от ненужного, чем отвечающим

Comment: @br3t http://www.filedropper.com/eugenrayswebsitecontactinfo вот тут понятнее будет. Когда откроете его в хроме (я под мозилу адаптивность не делаю - она там странная хотя хром тоже не очень правдоподобный, но довольно близкий к реальности по отображению html) зайдите в инструменты адаптивного дизайна и выберите iphone 5 в портретной ориентации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во всем виноват отрицательный `margin-left`. Более-менее приемлемый вариант - добавить следующие стили:

```
iv.block3 ul {
    margin: 10px 0px 30px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
iv.block3 li {
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: Вы были почти правы. Я еще поставить списку ширину  96% и все отлично стало.

Answer (score 2):

Обнулите отступы для списков, нечего придумывать костыли:

```
ul, ol, menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-padding: 0;
    -webkit-padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```